# How should I remove a region and zone in an Omega 3 sub theme?

Tags: theming, .info

I have a sub theme of Omega 3.

What is the correct way to completely remove regions and zones from my sub theme? Is it OK to just simply disable them and then remove them from the .info file?

These regions and zones are never going to be used and I want to simplfy the site by removing anything that isn't needed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the region and zone definition from the theme info file.